# Send data from serial port work, but not received

Tags: serial-port, converters, tcpclient, ethernet, tcpserver

I would like to communicate with a weaving machine that has a remote serial port. So I bought this [RS232/485/422 TO POE ETH](https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/RS232/485/422_TO_POE_ETH_(B))

Normally, the machine communicates with a PC with the following configuration : 2400 baud, 7 bits, even parity, CTS/DTR. But it doesn't work with this converter.

so I tried to see how it communicates with the Hercules software

I managed to send data from the PC's serial port (instead of the weaving machine for the duration of the test) with the following configuration[image]

When I send "blabla", the TCP terminal receives it.

[image]

[image]

But if I try to send the "ohoho" command from the PC to the converter's ethernet port, nothing happens.

[image]

Comment: This isn't a programming or even a SW development problem. You're having issues getting your equipment setup. You haven't even clearly described the connections you're using. "*I managed to send data from the PC's serial port*" -- What modern PC has a integrated or built-in serial port? An industrial PC? Why are you using flow-control? How do you know you have the correct serial cable?

Comment: I have a lenovo ThinkCentre E73, with a serial cable 03T8177 (https://www.monsieurcyberman.com/fr/20977-cable-adaptateur-serie-db-9-15-pin-com2-lenovo-31501173-fru-03t8177-thinkcentre-3664870066602.html)

The weighing machine is connected to Cable LC-RS25/LC-RS9/LC-RSopen (https://www.mt.com/dam/non-indexed/po/labtec/12_Miscellaneous/phased-out/1-documents/lc-rs25-9-open-ba-705157a.pdf) It's write "The following protocol must be set at the peripheral device: 2400 baud, 7 bits, even parity, CTS/DTR."

I've managed to configure the adapter with the serial cable, so it should be the right one